# The number of different prime factors of a special class of positive integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m_i\geq 2 (1\leq i\leq n)$ be $n$ pairwisely coprime positive integers and let $q_i\geq 2 (1\leq i\leq n)$ be $n$ arbitrary prime powers, let$A=\prod_{i=1}^n(({q_i}^{m_i}-1)/(q_i-1))$. Let $\sigma(A)$ be the number of different prime factors of A, is it true that $\sigma(A)\geq n$? If this is not true, is there a counterexample? Is there a good way to estimate $\sigma(A)$?

Comment: Bad idea to use $\sigma(A)$ for the number of prime factors of $A$ when 1) everyone else uses $\sigma$ for the sum of the divisors and 2) everyone else uses $\omega$ for the number of prime factors. 

Comment: If the q_i are all equal this should follow, at least modulo a few exceptions, from Zsigmondy's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy's_theorem

Comment: @Qiaochu: You don't need them to be equal, you just need them to be powers of the same prime. Also Zsigmondy's theorem helps when $m_i$'s have lots of divisors.

Answer (score 10):

No it's not true you have the following counterexample:
$$ \frac{2^5-1}{2-1} \times \frac{5^3-1}{5-1} = 31^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Let take a look to the special case when your $q_i$ are actually
$n$ distinct \emph{odd} prime numbers.

I use the standard notations :  $\omega(H)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $H$
and $\sigma(G)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $G.$

Put $B$ the product of all the $q_i^{m_i}$

then we have

$$
\sigma(B) = mB
$$

if $B$ is an odd $m$-multi-perfect number.

((sure, we do not known concrete examples of this, but...)

So, in this case

$$
\omega(B) = n
$$

and you have your lower bound attained.

luis

---

Comment: However, the question asks about $\omega(\sigma(B)) = \omega(mB)$, not $\omega(B)$.

Comment: warn: Huan used ``sigma'' to denote ``omega''.  Anyway what do you think is the interesting question here ?. No feedback seems known from the OP...